# reason for two eclipse warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

I was wondering what are the main reasons **why** eclipse warns developers about the following things:

1. The value of the local variable xxx is not used
2. The import XXX is never used

I'm thinking that one reason is to make code cleaner. Anyone knows a list of reasons behind those warnings (like memory concerns, and things like that)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that's about the only reason. You can disable them under Preferences

Comment: To make developer **aware** that there's something that s/he probably didn't do either by omission or because of some changed programming logic.

Comment: It will help you eliminate dead code. If you're removing the expression that uses it, it will indicate that you can also remove the expression that calculates it. I've also found bugs more than once when I got that warning and realized I used the wrong variable somewhere.

Comment: Unused imports sometimes may be a more serious problem - for example if you use groovy scripts in your application and replace one library with another but forget to remove the (now unused) imports you may encounter class not found errors in production.

Comment: You can disable them.But they are just basic java coding standards.

Comment: I don't want to disable, and I'm not unhappy with it or anything like that. I just want to know why it is good practice to delete unused imports and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly to make the code readable and avoid clutter - it's easy to loose track when a file starts getting large, and having non-functional lines of code are therefor best to avoid. It's mostly for readability... Well, and by removing unused imports, you ease the compilers job ever so slightly (read: *very* slightly).

If Eclipse notice an unused import or variable, you can be damn sure that the compiler does so as well (since eclipse is actually compiling the code while you code to generate those warnings). The compiler will try to optimize it as much as possible, so if it sees an unused variable (or import), it doesn't bother to include them in the compiled byte code.

But it's generally good coding style not to have unused code;

In Java and (most) other high-level languages, you generally don't have to worry about those things, since you don't have to manage memory-allocation. But supposing the compiler didn't catch it for whatever reason when compiling (perhaps if you were writing in another programming language), the object or data referenced by a variable would then be taking up memory space, and if you a lot of those unused variables that all took up memory space... that could potentially be a lot of memory used for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes why should you include code, that is never used?

I guess the compiler will remove this unused code anyway, but you should keep the code as clean as possible by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> The value of the local variable xxx is not used

It is declared when you only declare or assign a value to a variable, but you never used it for anything. It is warning you because it does nothing in your code, so it would be better to remove it.

> The import XXX is never used

The same thing as the other one. There is no need to import a classe you won't use, so Eclipse recommends you to remove the import, since it does nothing but pollute the code.

Comment: I suppose its just to reduce the memory footprint. With imports, My programming teacher said that it could leave openings for hackers to use and thats why you should never import entire packages like `.*`

Answer (score 1):

This prevents you that you writed `Unnecessary code`. According to the [help of Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm) (Java Compiler Errors/Warnings Preferences) this says :

> "When enabled, the compiler will issue an error or a warning whenever
>   a local variable is declared but its value never used within its
>   scope."

Answer (score 0):

you are unnecessarily `declared/imported` the `variable/import.`

Removing them keeps the code cleaner and easier to read.By default Eclipse warns you about unused private variables and methods.

**But do not change these warning preferences**,It's helpful to identify your unused code.

Comment: i understand that it makes it easier to read, but I was just wondering if it's also important to remove it for other reasons, like memory, possible errors (like dratewka mentioned above).

Comment: He is telling remove the unused import.Not the feature iguess.

Comment: But there are preferences that when you press ctrl+s ,i mean save in eclipse you can assign task there like remove unused imports,format code ..etc ...but you should know what are the mistakes you are doing by seeing them in eclipse.